# Acento em campo de comentário

Tags: php, codificação-de-caracteres, phpmailer

Preciso de uma ajuda para um situação que me parecia simples, tenho um form com um campo de comentário e ao enviar esse comentário por e-mail o mesmo aparece todo desconfigurado, estou usando a o phpMailer.

A página de código na página de contato está assim:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

E na página de processo já tentei algumas dicas repassadas, mas nenhuma com sucesso, já tentei a utf8_decode, utf8_encode, '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($message).'?=', já coloquei na página de processo os seguintes códigos:

```
ini_set('default_charset','UTF-8'); e
header(“Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1“,true)
```

E não resolveu também.
Alguém pode me dar alguma dica?

Comment: Você já tentou `utf8_decode($message)` ?

Comment: Olá @abfurlan, sim, já tentei essa solução e a mensagem está saindo assim: catÃ¡logo

Comment: Isso não faz sentido, voce ta dando ini_set como utf-8 e enviando as headers para o client como ISO (latin1), ou um ou outro.. a resposta do Leonardo Bosquett explica melhor...

Answer (score 7):

Se a tua página está efectivamente com *charset* `iso-8859-1`, podes fazer uso da função de PHP [utf8_encode()](https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> para codificar a mesma em `UTF-8`.

**Nota:**

No PHPMailer, tens que indicar o charset a utilizar para o envio da mensagem:

```
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
```

De qualquer forma, o *charset* do PHPMailer por defeito é o `iso-8859-1` conforme pode ser visto na [documentação](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=properties) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> o que indica que a tua página não estará em `iso-8859-1`, pelo menos o ficheiro que envia o email.

Answer (score 4):

Como resolvido nos comentários:

A questão foi resolvida aplicando a padronização do charset nos campos relevantes:

- Código por trás da página: chamar a função `header` com charset=utf-8 em todas as requisições.
- Salvar os documentos em UTF-8 (é possível converter um documento de ISO-8859-1 para UTF-8 pelo bloco de notas)
- No arquivo HTML a tag meta que define o charset deve estar presente e especificar que o documento está em UTF-8.

A requisição e resposta em HTTP agora estará trabalhando sempre em UTF-8, no caso do PHPMailer  você pode utilizar a função utf8_decode para trabalhar com as mensagens se necessário ou especificar seu atributo CharSet também para UTF-8 (ambas as formas realizam um processo de conversão).

Comment: O problema foi resolvido seguindo a dica do @LeonardoBosquett, patronizei a página de contato com o UTF-8 e na página do processo de envio também e para completar utilizei o utf8_decode também sugerido.